# jquery: the .val() of a <p> calls to random <br> while assigning values to its .text(), which needs to be in straight line

Tags: jquery, append

this is the jQuery i tried the below code which is posting the value to a text area to a div of content, it needs to post the values according to the given area, rather it is creating random new lines breaks

```js
jQuery('#directions-text').find('p').text('First, rub the chicken with a little olive oil (1 teaspoon should do the trick for a pound or so), salt and pepper.Heat another teaspoon of olive oil in a medium skillet over medium heat, place chicken breasts in and cook until edges are opaque, about 10 minutes.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="directions-text">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y2KD.png)

Comment: try, `html()` function

Comment: You do need to elaborate your problem. Add your html and create a runable snippet, please. What has this to do with any `.val()` or append?

Comment: @Webinion i already tried it

Comment: like if the text is in capital letters, without any space or random typing then it works good but if you type proper stuff then it call line breaks

Comment: @user3154108 please see the screen shot i attached ,,, there is no problem with the text area, the problem is when this text is assigned to another dive through append, that is where the problem is

Comment: @MaXeeKhan are you trying align text

Comment: @MaXeeKhan do want to display whole para in a single line ? if yes try adding css `#directions-text p{
          white-space: nowrap;
    }`

Comment: @MaXeeKhan Your code does not show any attempts to append to any div. I at least cannot tell what you are attempting and where your problem is.

Comment: no, not a complete single line according to the div size i set on the b back end which is 5 lines like i need to remove the random line breaks

Comment: @MaXeeKhan ok try this css  `#directions-text p{  text-align: justify; }`  and see

Comment: @user3154108  it gets the text dynamically from the back end and then finds it on the front end and display it

Comment: append is on the backend

Comment: jQuery('.badgeContainer').append('<div class="recipe-label direction-content" id="directions-text"><p>First, rub the chicken with a little olive oil (1 teaspoon should do the trick for a pound or so), salt and pepper.Heat another teaspoon of olive oil in a medium skillet over medium heat, place chicken breasts in and cook until edges are opaque, about 10 minutes.</p></div>');

Comment: this is the backend

Comment: `jQuery('.badgeContainer').append('<div class="recipe-label direction-content" id="directions-text"><p style="text-align: justify;">First, rub the chicken with a little olive oil (1 teaspoon should do the trick for a pound or so), salt and pepper.Heat another teaspoon of olive oil in a medium skillet over medium heat, place chicken breasts in and cook until edges are opaque, about 10 minutes.</p></div>');` try this form where ever your trying

Comment: that is another file

Comment: jQuery( document ).on('keyup', '#direction', function(){
var val = jQuery(this).val();
val = val.replace(/rn|n|r/g, '<br />');
var n = val.length;
jQuery('#directions-text ').find('p').html(val);
});

the keyup function

Comment: i figured it was calling for new line on character R and N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the key up function i think

```js
jQuery( document ).on('keyup', '#direction', function(){
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    val = val.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br.*?>/g, '\n');
    var n = val.length;
    jQuery('#directions-text ').find('p').html(val);
});
```

i replaced

```js
val = val.replace(/rn|n|r/g, '<br />');
```

with

```js
val = val.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<br.*?>/g, '\n');
```

and now it is working good